# Access method on React Context API from Children's Method

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I am new to React and trying to make context API. I have read some similar question but I can not get a solution.

My context provider file :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

    const MyContext = React.createContext();

    class ContextProvider extends Component {

        constructor(props) {
          super(props)

            this.state = {
               isLogin: false
            }   
        }  

        handleLogin = () => {   
          this.setState({
              isLogin : true
          })              
        }


      render() {
        return (    
          <MyContext.Provider value={{
              ...this.state,
              handleLogin : this.handleLogin
              }}>
             {this.props.children}
          </MyContext.Provider>
        );
      }
    }

    const ContextConsumer = MyContext.Consumer;
    export {ContextProvider, ContextConsumer};
```

I need to change the state by accessing handleLogin() in the ContextProvider.js after user successfull login :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {ContextConsumer} from "./ContextProvider";

class Login extends Component {

  onHandleSubmit = () => {

    // on submit login success :

    // --- how to call handleLogin() in ContextProvider.js here ? ----

  }

  render() { 
      return (
        <div> --- not expected here ---- </div>
     )
  }

}
```

BTW, sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your Login component is wrapped by the `ContextProvider` higher up in the hierarchy, you can access context inside class component by define a static contextType .

For that you need to export context from ContextProvider first like

```
export {ContextProvider, ContextConsumer, MyContext };
```

and then use it like

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {MyContext} from "./ContextProvider";
class Login extends Component {

  static contextType = MyContext;
  onHandleSubmit = () => {

    // on submit login success :

    this.context.handleLogin();

  }

  render() { 
      return (
        <div> {/* render content here */} </div>
     )
  }

}
```

However if you are using a version of react between 16.3.0 and 16.6.0, you need to pass on context using render props pattern like

```
class Login extends Component {

  onHandleSubmit = () => {

    // on submit login success :

    this.props.context.handleLogin();

  }

  render() { 
      return (
        <div> --- not expected here ---- </div>
     )
  }

} 

export default (props) => (
    <ContextConsumer>
        {values=> <Login {...props} context={values} />}
    </ContextConsumer>
)
```

Comment: Following your code and console.log(this.context). It shows the object.  Problem will be solved sure... Thanks SK